# What should I write logs to in production when using serilog?

Tags: .net, serilog, aws-fargate, datadog

I´am trying to setup serilog for for a project, but have some trouble understanding how it should be setup according to best practice for production.

I have followed this https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices/ , but I have some questions regarding the section **Configuration**. There he says;

> In .NET writing to Console is a blocking call and can have a
> significant performance impact.

and he links to https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down . Which again says that console is bad for perfomance and has this solution to the problem:

```
 if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == EnvironmentName.Development) 
        {
            config.AddConsole();
        }
```

Which only adds console if in development.

My question is: If I´am not logging to console for production what should i do? Should i write to file? RollingFile? What is the best perfomance vice and will it work on fargate?

My service is running on fargate with firelens sending logs to datadog.